# Entity Framework code first not picking up records inserted directly from the database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am using code-first approach of Entity Framework. I generated a database through it and then I then stored some data into the tables directly from SSMS.

But when I am trying to fetch this data, it is not getting returned while the records that I add through Entity Framework and my C# code do get returned.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to make code first fetch the records that was inserted directly from the database?

**Edit**

Just saw a very strange thing that the record I am adding from my c# code are not inserting to the database table and still every time they are getting fetched.

I don't know where are they actually stored and from where it is picking them up because I don't see them in my database table.

**Edit - Details**

This is where the code first created data base

[image]

This is my method to add and retrieve the data

[image]

This is the result I am getting when I hit the API

[image]

This is the database generated by code first

[image]

But see there is no result in the table when I run the query in the database

[image]

Really strange!!! That where is it storing the records and from where is it fetching it!!

Connection string

```
<add name="RestaurantDbContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=RestaurantReview;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: **SHOW US SOME CODE!** We cannot possibly help you if you're not showing us what you're doing ......**HOW** are you trying to fetch the data from the database? What is the table structure in your database - and how did you add rows to the table from SSMS?

Comment: @marc_s - Added detailed description

Comment: Can you please show us the **connection string** you're using?

Comment: @marc_s - Added. Please check

Comment: @marc_s - Is providerName the problem? Is it storing it somewhere in sql lite in some file or something rather than actual sql server because of that? But the same connection string created database in sql server

Comment: @marc_s - Just to check I tried removing providerName from the connection string but it is still the same

Comment: No, `System.Data.SqlClient` **is** the **SQL Server** version of the connection string - that's definitely not the problem.

Comment: @marc_s - I have posted the answer. I found that it is using I don't know what but some other sever, please check my answer. However I am still confused how it is dong this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192858/discussion-between-pawan-nogariya-and-marc-s).

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string to make sure your program is connecting to the same DB as SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason, it is creating database to different server than `.`

[image]

If anybody could please explain me the difference between `Data Source =.` and `DataSource: (localdb)\mssqllocaldb`

In my connection string I specifically said this `Data Source =.` and it is still creating the database here but then later when he make changes it does it here `DataSource: (localdb)\mssqllocaldb`